# How get all keys when using POJO as key for Spring Redis cache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Spring Data Redis to do my caching and I'm caching with the keys as objects, not strings. How do I find all the keys in a cache this way?

When I try to use the `StringRedisSerializer()` I get a class cast exception saying the object cannot be cast to a string.

When I try the `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer`, it throws the exception:

> Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('¬' (code 172)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

How can I get all the keys?

I'm caching via the `@Cacheable` annotation.

```
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheConfig
{
    public static final String REDIS_CACHE_MGR = "RedisCacheManager";

    @Value( "${spring.redis.cluster}" )
    private List<String> cluster;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory()
    {
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(
            new RedisClusterConfiguration( cluster )
        );

        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf)
    {

        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory( cf );
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager redisCacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) throws EagleCacheException
    {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager( redisTemplate );

        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration( 3600 );

        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to monitor your Redis cache, you can use RedisDesktopManager tool. Can you please share a little more stack trace?

Comment: @Rakesh I was able to get rid of the error, but i still can't figure out how to find all keys. I have to know about a key beforehand to get it from the cache manager. How would i get all keys when they're objects?

Comment: Usually, that object's hashkey is used as a key to store in Redis cache. Well, I'm yet to find a way to get all keys through the application but you check the keys from the desktop tool.

Comment: posted the answer, Please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use

`redisTemplate.keys("*")`

But before that make sure that your redisTemplate uses correct serializers. In case of string keys:

`redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer())`

Comment: Use of this command on a production server is discouraged since it's a blocking call that can significantly degrade your Redis server's performance with large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Autowire your RedisTemplate somewhere and try this

```
redisTemplate.keys("*")
```

Comment: It worked fine in my case. Maybe you do not have anything in your cache yet? Did you try using the desktop tool?

Comment: yes, i verified i have a key in there but still nothing shows from that method.

Comment: RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = context.getBean(RedisTemplate.class);redisTemplate.keys("*"); This is what I did, I'll try finding other ways though and will update my answer

Comment: I'll try that. i was getting it from the cache via `getNativeCache()`